# In Vue, is it possible to allow users to create Router Links?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am making a CRUD system using Vue. So far I have made it so that logged in users can administer the content in the application, like adding/updating/deleting text and images.
But let us say the user wants to create a button, and that button needs to link to somewhere, like to a different component.
How is this achieved?

If it is not possible to create router links, then is there at least some way I can allow users to add a normal url address to a block of text?

example:

"Enter name for your link"

"Enter URL for your link"

This is what the my current code looks like. I added an url-type input field, because I believe this is where I need to start, but I am not sure where to go from here.

```
<template>
<AdminNavbar/>
   <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <h4>Create new content</h4>
      <input type="text" required placeholder="Insert title" v-model="cardTitle">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="Insert descriptiob" v-model="cardDescription">
      <label>Add a link:</label>
      <input type="url" v-model="cardLink">
      <label>Upload image</label>
      <input type="file" @change="handleChange">
      <div class="error">{{ fileError }}</div>
      <button v-if="!isPending">Create</button>
      <button v-else disabled>Saving...</button>
   </form>
</template>

<script>

import slugify from 'slugify'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import useStorage from '@/composables/useStorage'
import useCollection from '@/composables/useCollection'
import { timestamp } from '@/firebase/config'
import AdminNavbar from '@/components/AdminNavbar.vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router' 

export default {

   components: {
      AdminNavbar
   },

    setup() {
       const slug = ref(null)
       const { filePath, url, uploadImage } = useStorage()
       const { error, addDoc } = useCollection('cards')
       const cardTitle = ref('')
       const cardDescription = ref('')
       const cardLink = ref('')
       const file = ref(null)
       const fileError = ref(null)
       const isPending = ref(false)
       const router = useRouter();

       const handleSubmit = async () => {
         if (cardTitle.value) {
             slug.value = slugify(cardTitle.value, {
                replacement: '-',
                remove: /[*+~.()'"!:@]/g,
                lower: true
             })
          }
          if (file.value) {
             isPending.value = true
             await uploadImage(file.value)
             await addDoc({
                slug: slug.value,
                cardTitle: cardTitle.value,
                cardDescription: cardDescription.value,
                cardLink: cardLink.value,
                cardImage: url.value,
                filePath: filePath.value,
                createdAt: timestamp()
             })
             isPending.value = false
             if(!error.value) {
                router.push({ name: "Home" })
             }
          }
       }

       // allowed file types

       const types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']

       const handleChange = (e) => {
          const selected = e.target.files[0]
          console.log(selected)

          if (selected && types.includes(selected.type)) {
             file.value = selected
             fileError.value = null 
          } else {
             file.value = null
             fileError.value = 'Please select an image of the type JPG or PNG'
          }
       }

       return {
          slug,
          cardTitle,
          cardDescription,
          cardLink,
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange,
          fileError,
          file,
          isPending
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would create a route that accepts 2 arguments.  Example: /images/{user}/{image-slug}.  So now when an image is linked this route will route to the component and you can load the image based on the user and the slug.  Example: http://example.com/images/1/imagename

Comment: I am sorry. I read your answer a few times, but I don't think I completely understand it. As I understand it, you suggest that I link a route a specific element (in this case an image), but what I want is for users to enter some text in an input field, and then I want to give them the option to choose a route (or a hyperlink) and add it to that piece of text. I know this can be easily achieved with hyperlinks in a WYSIWYG editor, but I am looking for a method similar to what you do in WordPress and other CMS applications.